# Communication between Threads without killing the thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I am creating a WPF application in which i need a thread which should  continuously read the empty files from a folder ( file name contains the pids and the name of the process and unique plan name) and should check that the the pid with same process name exist in the system no not.

if thread founds any process that has crashed and not exist in the system , it should send the plan name to the main UI thread without exiting and should continue its work.

I have implemented the 1 part. but have no idea how to implement the 2 part .

Comment: What class are you using for the threading work?

Answer (score 5):

"Sending to the main thread" typically means using the main thread's Dispatcher, and calling `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to marshal a delegate which will run on the main (UI) thread.

You could use this to add the "plan name" back into a collection on the main thread, as needed.

Comment: can you please give me some link. i searched for begininvoke but i cannot find a way to get data from the thread to UI thread. some code will be very useful..

Comment: @RATHI See: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by creating a shared collection that contains the crashed process details. I would then create a UI timer that at set intervals polled the collection to see what was in it. This scheme would obviously need some kind of lock (probably a ReaderWriterLock) to prevent faulty reads from the collection.